# What goes with marks - much or many?

Tags: modifiers

1) How many marks do I need to get in order t get into the college?

2) How much marks do I need to get in order to get into the college?

Does the 2nd sentence without the word marks sound better? " How much do I need to get..."

Comment: What did you find when you googled `many vs much`?

Comment: If by *marks* you mean *grades*, neither *many* nor *much* is appropriate. Marks are not counted or measured in that way—you don't have a quantity or measurement of them. Instead, you would ask ***What*** *marks do I need to get in order to get into college?* Or when you say *marks* are you referring to the currency and asking how much it *costs* for tuition?

Comment: @Jason Bassford you maybe completely correct in your statement, in the area, region, country you live in. However you would not be where I live. All the marks from all subjects taken in the final examination (including Physical Education) are totalled and your accumulative mark acts as a bench mark for entrance to the relative School, College, University.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Most colleges in India have marks instead of grades as the yardstick for taking students, for example, one might need to score at least 230 out of 300 to get into a particular college.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 is correct English, Sentence 2 would not be used.However you could make sentence 1 better, and simpler by asking

> How many marks do I need to get into college?

"How much do I need to get into college" would be understood to mean "How much money do I need to get into college"

Comment: Thank you. Would you use that sentence yourself for inquiring about the cut-off marks of any college or would you use a different sentence?

Comment: That sentence does imply asking for the minimum requirement. If you had a particular college in mind then you could ask "_How many marks do I need to get into [name of college] ?_"

Comment: How about if we do away with the word "marks" and just say "How much do I need to score to get into the college?" Would this be alright?

Comment: @Shivam No, as I said in my answer, in idiomatic English this would be understood as  "How much **money** do I need to go to college"

Comment: Even if we use the word score?

Comment: What is your aversion to the word "marks"? Unfortunately ["_score_"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/score) has a number of other meanings which might get you misunderstood. For example your sentence _could_ be misinterpreted as "_How much [money] do I have to acquire illegally ..._" ! Using the word "_marks_" is unambiguous.

Comment: I was just looking for other ways to ask the same question. Thanks.